# Is it possible to create multiple function on this code?

Tags: javascript, html

Here I want to try to create multiple functions for some parts of this code. But I don't know how to do it. When I create multiple functions, the outputs are not working.

Because this is about load file .txt, you can just load a random txt file or just fill the txt with some numbers.

Here's the code : http://jsfiddle.net/3149vvcf/1/

```
window.onload = function() { //1. and this is the part what i want to create function
    var loadFile = document.getElementById('loadFile'); 
    loadFile.addEventListener('change', function(e) { 
        var file = loadFile.files[0]; 
        var textType = /text.*/; 

        if (file.type.match(textType)) { 
            var read = new FileReader();
            read.readAsText(file); 

            read.onload = function(e) { //2. and this one too
                var result = read.result;
                circle(350, 100, 30, "yellow", "blue", result);
...
```

can i just change it to this code?

```
function file() { //change it like this?
    var loadFile = document.getElementById('loadFile'); 
    loadFile.addEventListener('change', function(e) { 
        var file = loadFile.files[0]; 
        var textType = /text.*/; 

        if (file.type.match(textType)) { 
            var read = new FileReader();
            read.readAsText(file); 
        }
    }
}

function result(e) {
    var result = read.result;
    circle(350, 100, 30, "yellow", "blue", result);
    file();
}

result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some confusion on the order of the functions there

```
// this guy should in "result" scope as well
var read;

function file() { //change it like this?
    var loadFile = document.getElementById('loadFile'); 
    loadFile.addEventListener('change', function(e) { 
      var file = loadFile.files[0]; 
      var textType = /text.*/; 

      if (file.type.match(textType)) {
          read = new FileReader();
          read.readAsText(file);

          read.onload = result;
      }
    });
}

function result(e) {
  var result = read.result;
  circle(350, 100, 30, "yellow", "blue", result);
  ... more stuff here
}

// on window load read the file
window.onload = file;
```